# how to collect all the points in NSBezierpath to draw

Tags: objective-c

I have store all the points in the array and pass to the NSBeizerPath so that it can draw through that path.The code i have implemented is as follows:

```
- (void)drawPath:(NSPoint)inStartPoint toLastPoint:(NSPoint)inEndPoint
{

    NSBezierPath* path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    NSLog(@"Drawing path....");
    [path moveToPoint:inStartPoint]; 
    [path lineToPoint:inEndPoint];    
    [mColor set];
    [path fill];
    [path stroke];
}
```

This is drawing to only the startpoint and end point now how to draw where the cursor moves.

Comment: In your question, I don't understand whether you already have the points stored in an array or whether you're looking for a way to record the mouse movements. And from "cursor" I suspect we're talking about MacOS here. Please add a tag to your question indicating the operating system.

Comment: With regard to following the mouse, what have you tried?